# I have video URL and want to delete it from the iPhone using this URl

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have created a app that stores video, now I want to remove that video when a user clicks a remove button. I am using `AVFoundation` for record video.

My app camera gives me an output URL like this:

```
file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/4B2E02E5-3EE2-493E-8ECF-4B1DA29B9387/tmp/output.mov
```

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
- (void) removeFile:(NSURL *)fileURL
{

    NSString *filePath = [fileURL path];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"here it is : %@",fileURL);
        NSError *error;
        // Attempt to delete the file at filePath2
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error] != YES)
            NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

        // Show contents of Documents directory
        NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
              [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:filePath error:&error]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

```
   - (IBAction)videoWillDelete:(id)sender {

        NSString *strPath =  [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];

        NSLog(@"file is:%@",strPath);

        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:strPath]==YES) {
            NSLog(@"file is deletebale");
        }else {
            NSLog(@"file is not deletebale");
        }

        NSError *error;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:strPath]) {

            BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];

            if (!success) {
                NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }

    }
```

My log file has:

```
2012-11-02 17:33:21.836 AVFoundationCam[1791:707] file is:/var/mobile/Applications/4B2E02E5-3EE2-493E-8ECF-4B1DA29B9387/output.mov

2012-11-02 17:33:21.838 AVFoundationCam[1791:707] file is not deletebale
```

This function is what I use to store data in the iPhone:

```
else {  
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

                                        if (error) {
                                            if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManager:didFailWithError:)]) {
                                                [[self delegate] captureManager:self didFailWithError:error];
                                            }                                           
                                        }

                                        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported]) {
                                            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:[self backgroundRecordingID]];
                                        }

                                        if ([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(captureManagerRecordingFinished:)]) {
                                            [[self delegate] captureManagerRecordingFinished:self];
                                        }
                                    }];
        //[library release];
    }
}
```

Comment: As you did not add any related information, does it mean `removeItemAtPath` returns `YES` and the `error` is `nil` ?

Comment: Which type of error log, could you put the log?

Comment: and for Documents directory its give me null

Comment: maybe?: NSString *strPath =  [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/output.mov"];

Answer (score 0):

U can get `Document` `Directory` `path` like this:

```
NSString *strPath =  [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
```

Now remove item like this:

```
NSError *error;
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:strPath]) {
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File removed  at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
  }
  else
{
    NSLog(@"file not exists"); 
}
```

Comment: do i have to change value at stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"

Comment: yes and again add your file name in like this: [strPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameHere];

Comment: it said that file is not deletable why?

Answer (score 0):

Check `[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"tmp/output.mov"];` is the same with   the outputFileURL in `[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:outputFileURL
                                    completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {`

Answer (score 0):

answer is Simple, 
you cannot delete file from Document Directory. Its Readable and  writeable only.

You can achieve your purpose by giving path for tmp directory , and then for saving purpose move it from the tmp path to document directory. Thats it.