# delete files from database permanently ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsfilemanager

I am Making an Audio recorder(m4a extension files). I am Giving a particular URL for the output of the recorded File(in directory). 
I am able to play it, save the path of the file in database and can retrieve it later. EVery thing is going Fine. BUT I am not able to delete the saved/unsaved files. Every time I record an audio , the file is taking a permanent space. Am not able to delete them.

I tried it over internet(stackoverflow ofcourse). I got Links like this: **[I have video URL and want to delete it from the iPhone using this URl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193661/i-have-video-url-and-want-to-delete-it-from-the-iphone-using-this-url)**

But they are showing **COCOA ERROR 4** when ever i try to delete them using codes like this:  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];

Please suggest, and reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the **path earlier** i was getting , at which i was **unable to write file**

**/var/mobile/Applications/8584F54E-75D2-4833-8826-29C125E53DBC/Library/Documentation/291013193758w.png**

This morning, I just run my code once again ,. now its showing path

**/var/mobile/Applications/DDA14123-6A88-4756-B2E4-C4A3AA39AA5B/Documents/291013081335test.png**

on this path am **able to write** my file

the Difference between two paths is that, **first one is of Library/Documentation** , where **as second one is of Documents**

**dont know the difference, but it is working now**

Answer (score 0):

You typically accomplish this for resources you've saved in your Apps documents directory like this:

```
unlink([pathForURL UTF8String]);
```

where `pathForURL` is an NSString that describes the path to the resource you're deleting.

Comment: hi Ryan, I followed what u said in above comment, but failed once again. 
i have added above something. please have a look , and help.
I shall be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

There may be case that file path which you provide is not correct. If its correct then try following with URL, it might solve your issue

```
NSString *str= [outputFieldURL absoluteString];

    NSError *error;

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
    BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error];


    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"Error removing file at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"File removed  at path: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

Before deleting the file you have to check file there or not :

```
 NSFileManager* manager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
 if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    [manager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
 }
```

Comment: yeah the problem was of path, I have added my answer, its working now.  But dont know the exact answer.